# android api: child view is still visible with a parent view set to INVISIBLE

Tags: android, xml, view, children, invisible

I have 3 fragments in my app. The layout of the 3rd fragment has the following xml:

```
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:id="@+id/settings_btns_container"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save"
                android:id="@+id/save"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

The settings_btns_container tablerow is set invisible so it doesn't show up on initial load. When onCreate is called, everything works as expected. However, when the fragment goes out of scope (1st fragment is selected), when we come back to the 3rd fragment, the children of this tablerow container become visible. I have added the following explicit code in onCreate():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
btn_container_ui = (TableRow) settings_view.findViewById(R.id.settings_btns_container);
/*
some other code
...
*/
btn_container_ui.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Whether I set it to INVISIBLE or GONE is irrelevant, the children are still visible. I checked the value of the parent tablerow and it is set to 4, which is the value of INVISIBLE constant. Setting children themselves to INVISIBLE hides them with no problem, but I wanted to hide the entire parent, so I don't have to go through children one by one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think making parent invisible implies children will become invisible too, I think you must set each child invisible one by one

Comment: why require to set for every child view one by one @TomTsagk

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps but, the isShown() method of the View class returns true if the view and all of its ancestors are visible.